# How fast do you have to be to punch through a steel door?

Tags: physics, hard-science, mathematics

Assuming the person is durable enough to not break his hand, how fast would he have to move his fist to punch completely through a solid steel door that is 1 inch thick?

Comment: If you assume the hand ist hard enough to do that, it is not a matter of speed but mainly of force. If you don't apply enough force, your hand just pushes against the steel without moving anything. If the force is high enough, your hand will break through the steel even if you move it slow. The form of the broken steel will just be different. So you have to specify how you want to break the steel.

Comment: A clean hole punched in it like aluminum foil.

Comment: Unfortunately, I doubt you'll get a clear answer to this. There is a sad lack of concrete science dedicated to punching through things, I've found. (https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/142841/how-much-force-would-your-fist-need-to-strike-with-to-punch-through-a-human-body) A bummer for those of us who are curious about the actual specifications of our super powered characters, lol.

Comment: Are the fist arm of normal human mass, or this mass is somehow increased?

Comment: If you ask here, folks don't know the answer (it's apparently REALLY complicated to figure out, since so many variables are involved) and if you ask the hard science stacks (physics SE, etc.) they shut your question down for being too unrealistic due to any handwaving (like assuming your super powered character won't break his fist in the first place). Oh well. I hope you do get what you're looking for anyway...

Comment: @Alexander normal mass, although a proper punch would probably include the mass of the entire upper body.

Comment: @Praearcturus should we assume that the entire body is moving as a rigid projectile? This would let us to define our problem as some 80 kg missile striking 25.4 mm (1 inch) steel armor.

Comment: @Alexander sure, he weighs 304 lb.

Comment: No matter how fast the person's arm is moving it won't punch through the door. What will happen is that if the hand moves fast enough it will push the entire door off the hinges. If you want to punch a hole through the door you will need a projectile with a small cross section. A high velocity bullet will punch through; a cannon ball will just push the door aside. (It is a question of how much energy is needed to punch a hole compared to how much energy is needed to break the hinges, which comes at comparing the cross section of the projectile with the cross section of the hinges.)

Comment: @AlexP "push the entire door off the hinges" - what if the door opens outside? :)

Comment: @AlexP assume the hinges are stronger than the door

Comment: The hinges, bolts etc. cannot be stronger than the door area which connects then to the door. So it comes down to the area of a human fist and the total area of the connections between the door and the hinges or bolts.

Comment: To help with visualising the kinds of forces involved in something like this, here's a short Mythbusters clip of [a 1 inch steel plate hitting a car](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mh835unue5w) so hard that it behaves like a *wet noodle*. Not quite the same as punching a nice round hole, but you get an idea of just how much *destruction* super-punch-man is going to cause if he actually tries to do this 

Comment: that works yeah

Comment: "will not break his hand" - You will really have to stretch this. You cannot punch through like in cartoons with enough speed.

The mechanism of penetrating steel with high velocity works by firing a shot (or your fist) at the steel at a speed so great that at impact, the rigidity of the materials are negligible compared to the forces of acceleration. So, the penetration process becomes purely hydrodynamics.

That is what happens in non-explosive armor-piercing ammunition - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armour-piercing_fin-stabilized_discarding_sabot

Comment: Sometimes the best answer doesn't require science but trial and error. Screws sheer differently than 1095 steel first off. Doors that are 2 inches solid steel don't exist unless in a vault. Which would have large capacity metal hinges. Surrounded by a cement door jamb. A normal metal exterior door is usually filled with foam.
I don't care how strong you are, no one going to punch a door open in one hit.
Kick a door however... multiple kicks or even big enough person will be able to kick the door open in one kick. However no metal will give way. The wood door jamb will split where the lock goes

Comment: Hi Aaron, welcome to Worldbuilding! Errm, you're not answering the question anywhere: the [hard-science] tag demands answers have "unequivocal proof that answers are correct through the use of equations, empirical evidence, scientific papers, etc.". Furthermore, the OP describes a specific scenario: those are the given parameters, and it doesn't matter whether it's realistic (that's kind of what this SE is about). Please take the [Tour] to learn more about this site :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As clarified in the comments, the door is an ideal immovable door and we are to ignore that in a normal door the hinges or bolts which hold it closed will shear long before a big fat projectile like a human fist will punch a hole.

In this idealized case, we can compute an approximation of the necessary velocity of an non-deformable human fist backed up by the entire weight of the unbreakable unbendable human to punch through:

- The [shear strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_strength) of steel is about 350 to 1400 MPa (50,000 to 200,000 psi). Let's assume 1000 MPa. (To get an idea of how much this is, 1000 MPa is about 10,000 atmospheres.)
- To punch a neat hole, we must apply enough force to overcome the shear strength of the 25 mm of steel along the circumference of the hole; let's say that the circumference of the fist is about 400mm (it's a big fist but not huge).
- 400 mm circumference times 25 mm depth is 10,000 square mm, or 0.01 square meters.
- 0.01 square meters times 1000 megapascal is 10 meganewton. (For a rough idea of bigness, that's about 1000 tons-force.)
- 10 meganewton of force applied on a 100 kg body (big fist, big man) gives an acceleration of 100,000 meters per second squared.
- With a uniform acceleration $a$, a body will come to rest in a given space $S$ (= the thickness of the door in our case) when it starts with a velocity $v = \sqrt{2aS}$. Plugging in the numbers, we find that $v = \sqrt{2 \times 100,000 \times 0.025} = 71 \,\text{m/s}$. That's about 250 km/h or 155 mph.

Comment: How do you calculate S

Comment: @Praearcturus: It's the thickness of the door. The fist must travel at least one inch. (If the initial speed is *higher* then the fist won't come to a stop and will continue moving after punching clean through the door; but it *must* travel at least a distance equal to the thickness of the door, or else it won't punch completely through.)

Comment: This seems suspect. Ignoring that they would pulverize their fist, 155mph doesn't seem as far away from peak human athleticism as I assumed this would be. And you didn't even choose the lowest number for steel's shear strength.

Comment: @JohnO: (It has no relationship with reality. In reality, the human would go splash. The strength in compression of human bones is very very much inferior to the strength of steel; and the bones in the hand are *tiny*. In fact, a human can easily break their bones if they hit a steel door running at full speed.) It's a 100 kg indestructible body hitting an one inch steel plate at 250 km/h over a small area (about 127 cm² or 20 sq.in.). For a mental picture, imagine a 100 kg (200 pound) cannon ball hitting the plate. Have you seen how a car looks like after hitting a wall at 250 km/h?

Comment: @JohnO if you had read the question you would know that he is indestructible.

Comment: It's just a little incredible to me that the splashy thing can actually get that close to the force required, even if it's too splashy to do do anything other than "splat".

Comment: @JohnO: It is **not splashy** at all. It is made of adamantium. That's what the question requests. Forget about the word "human". It is clarified in comments that we are to assume that the whole body is moving like a rigid projectile.

Comment: Isn't the right answer that speed doesn't matter at all? The human could be slow as a hydraulic press and (given enough force, and the assumption that they are immovable) just punch through the door regardless...